What is the correct way to mapped data received from API to domain entity within DDD conception?
I'm diving into the topic of pure architecture and DDD. I can't understand how to properly map data received from API and into the domain entity.
create just a DataMapper class with static methods:
toDomain, toPersistance, fromApiToDomain?

Here you can see an documented example in  Java and Spring boot. Hexagonal architecture is a way to separate domain code from infrastructure code.

In the common case, you're going to take the message delivered to your API, parse it into a value, and then pass that value to the domain model and let the model decide what to do.
It's not really all that different from how you would handle input from an app, or input via batch processing of a report.
To choose a specific example: your Cargo domain is going to care a lot about the information content of Handling Events (why did that container unload at SESTO? it's supposed to go to AUMEL) than it cares about the plumbing that delivers the handling event.

For JSON, and other general purpose message formats, it may be useful to think of the parsing as happening in two phases; one that takes bytes/text and turns it into a general purpose in memory representation of the document, and then a second bespoke element that takes the general purpose representation and convert it to the form your domain model expects.

The sad truth is that (mapping) belongs to a class of problems that is both boring and non-trivial.  -- Einar W. Høst



create just a DataMapper class with static methods: toDomain, toPersistance, fromApiToDomain?

As far as organizing the code is concerned; you (and your team?) are the ones charged to maintain it; I'm not sure anyone else deserves a vote.
That said, information hiding is likely to be a useful consideration, as is writing code that is easy to delete.
